# Bell curve and normal distribution and the empirical rule

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

This is an assignment on the 68-95-97 rule - or rather a close idea. Specifically we go for 68-90-95, but you'll see.

Let's assume we have a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and draw a sample of 100 elements from it, $X_1,X_2,...X_{100}$. We now define;
$$M(t) = E\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{100} \textbf{1}_{[-t,t]}(X_i-\mu)\bigg]$$

Where the indicator function $\textbf{1}_{[-t,t]}$ is;
$$\textbf{1}_{[-t,t]}(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if } x\in[-t,t]\\
0&\text{if } x\notin[-t,t]
\end{cases}$$

That is, the function $M(t)$ is the expected number of samples in the interval $\mu-t$ to $\mu+t$.

**Now; to the question:** How does one show the desired results;
$M(\sigma)\approx 68, M(\frac{5}{3}\sigma)\approx 90, M(2\sigma)\approx 95$?

**p.s.** I am familiar with the derivation that "simply" uses the CDF to calculate the given values, but it seems to me that this assignment wants to do it without the CDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution will essentially say something like $$M_n(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(-t \le X_i-\mu \le t)\\= n \left(\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{t}{\sigma} \right)-\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{-t}{\sigma} \right)\right) \\= n\left( \Phi\left( \frac{t}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left( \frac{-t}{\sigma}\right)\right)\\= n\left( 2\Phi\left( \frac{t}{\sigma}\right) - 1\right)$$
so you cannot escape the normal cumulative distribution function.  For example with $n=100$ and $t=\sigma$ you get $M_n(\sigma)=100\left( 2\Phi\left( 1\right) - 1\right)\approx 68.27$

Comment: Great! I was worried that I was missing something - i.e. that there was some way to do this without the CDF.